# Google data studio Date range - Add upcoming event

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

Is it any possibility to select all values based on date range which is >= date which selected in data studio? Or this is still not supported.

**P.S.** Any other way to get an upcoming event, like if currently 8th of October, it will display which event(holiday) will be next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've achieved this in reports is to have a dimension that reflects whether the event is in the future, "Future"/"Past".

I've then filtered the table by this dimension so it only shows future events and then changed the Default Date Range to "All Date Range".

The table will now show all future events.

Comment: Yes, I know this logic, that's why I specify "based on date range" , as far as I understood my idea is impossible currently. (

Comment: Yes, there's no way to do it based on comparing date ranges currently. I was answering your "Any other way" part.